# How can I persist HABTM relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working on a chat, using HABTM relationship.
Basically, Users have many chats and Chats have many Users. Here's the Chat :

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

end
```

And here's the User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :chats
  ...
```

I got my tables, several users and several Chats

In Rails console, I tried

`User.find(1).chats << Chat.find(1)`

But when I type User.find(1).chats, I get a []
I also tried with

`user = User.find(1)`

`user.chats << Chat.find(1)`

`user.save`

Didn't work either. What am I missing ?

Here's the migration for the HABTM

```
class CreateChatsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :chats_users do |t|
      t.belongs_to :chat, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT - Using `has_many, through:` relationship

Chat :

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, through: :messages

end
```

User :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :chats, through: :messages
....
```

Message :

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chat
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And finally, the migration:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.belongs_to :chat, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.datetime :message_date
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Weird, mind assigning everything and making sure that everything is present?

Comment: Can you show your migration for users_chats?

Comment: Most folks these days would recommend using `has_many, through:` relationships.  Here's the latest article on the subject. http://cobwwweb.com/why-i-dont-use-has-and-belongs-to-many-in-rails.  I understand this won't answer your question directly but I strongly recommend switching if you are able.

Comment: @sebsonic2o , yep, I just added it in latest edit !

Comment: @JoeEssey , I'll take a look, but I started using RoR 4 weeks ago, still new to this stuff

Comment: Open the console and type: `User.find(1).chats.to_sql` and show what you'll get.

Comment: @BroiSatse , I get this : [7] pry(main)> User.find(74).chats.to_sql
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 74]]
=> "SELECT \"chats\".* FROM \"chats\" INNER JOIN \"chats_users\" ON \"chats\".\"id\" = \"chats_users\".\"chat_id\" WHERE \"chats_users\".\"user_id\" = 74"

Comment: @JoeEssey , I tried your method using ```has_many, through```, but I got the exact same problem : I can assign chats to users, but it is not persisted. I edited question to match new methods

Comment: @PierreOlivierTran - Can you go directly to your database and check whether there is anything there? This is quite interesting as it's all fine in the code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found my mistake.

First of all, yeah, it's better to use HMT relationship. You can use the one I posted in my last edit.

All you have to do is make sure that you have a user, a Chat, and a message that links both of em ( this is the one I missed)

Answer (score 0):

I believe RoR will not allow HABTM to work if you don't have `id: false` in your migration. See below:

```
class CreateChatsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :chats_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :chat, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

If you are just experimenting on your local development environment, you can just change your migration, and then `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`. This will drop the database, and run all your migrations. Not to be done in production ever!

If not, you can generate a new migration `rails g migration remove_id_from_chats_users id:primary_key` to remove the `id` column, and run `rake db:migrate`.